# Tab-Menu, Javascript, Focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, focus

I have a little problem with my tab menu. Namely, the buttons lose focus as soon as the visitor clicks anywhere on the website. I am aware that this is normal, but I would like to keep the focus or otherwise keep the style. I've tried a few things now, but I can't get anywhere, maybe you could help me. Thank you very much!

The Menu:

```
<div id="tab_bar">
                        <button id="blink1" class="tab_bar_item_left tab_button tablink" onClick="openLink(event, 'link1')" autofocus>link1</button>
                        <button id="blink2" class="tab_bar_item_left tab_button tablink" onClick="openLink(event, 'link2')">link2</button>
                        <button id="blink3" class="tab_bar_item_left tab_button tablink" onClick="openLink(event,'link3')">link3</button>
                        <button id="blink4" class="tab_bar_item_left tab_button tablink" onClick="openLink(event, 'link4')">link4</button>
                        <button id="blink5" class="tab_bar_item_right tab_button tablink" onClick="openLink(event, 'link5')">link5</button>
                        <button id="blink6" class="tab_bar_item_right tab_button tablink" onClick="openLink(event, 'link6')">link6</button>
                    </div>
```

The Content Div:

```
<div id="link1" class="content" style="display: flex;">
<div id="link1_content">
<h1>Some Text</1>
</div>
</div>
```

The Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function openLink(evt, animName) {
            var i, x, tablinks;
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" tab_bar_item_left tab_button tablink", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(animName).style.display = "flex";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " tab_bar_item_left tab_button tablink";
        }
        function checkMenu(evt, animName) {
            if (document.getElementById(animName).style.display == 'flex') { 
            document.getElementById("b" + animName).focus();
        }
        }
    </script>
```

The Button Style:focus:

```
#site #menu #tab_box #tab_bar .tab_button:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgba(20, 33, 45);
}
```

Comment: May be you can use a class called 'active' in which css properties should be same as focus and set this class whenever button loose focus by using onblur event listener.

Comment: onblur and a new css element was a great idea, but i solve it otherwise.
I add the following code to the script and it worked like a charm:

var x = document.getElementById(animName);
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
 if (y.length === 0) {
    //
 } else {
  y[0].classList.remove('active');
 }
 if(window.getComputedStyle(x).display === "flex") {
 document.getElementById("b" + animName).className += ' active';
 }